# Custom and Dynamic content UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I've implemented a custom UITableViewCell (programmatically). Here a little bit of my code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
      // Here I initialize three labels with 2 vertical constraints between each other
    }

    return self;
}
```

And when I launch my application I can see:

```
My label 1

|-vertical constraint-|

My label 2

|-vertical constraint-|

My label 3
```

Everything is ok when my three labels have text, however some of them may not have a text and my application displays:

```
My label 1

|-vertical constraint-|

|-vertical constraint-|

My label 3
```

So I need to remove or not initialize the related label and add/remove the right constraints to display:

```
My label 1

|-vertical constraint-|

My label 3
```

Where do I have to do this? I cannot do this in `initWithStyle` because I don´t know if my labels text have values yet:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
    cell.name.text = name;
    cell.username.text = username;
    cell.description.text = description;

    return cell
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a model class with the name, username and description and you can inject that model into the cell through a method like `configureWithModel:`.
Then in the cell you can dynamically create your labels.
In your case i think you can create the labels in the cell initializer and when the model is injected you just check to see what properties of the model are available and you can hide some of the labels.
If you go with this approach i recommend you to implement the `prepareForReuse` and make the labels visible again, otherwise when a cell is reused and a label that was previously hidden it could show up hidden when you don't want that.

Comment: In the configure method where the model is injected.